# User Object access in Ajax Toolkit

Tags: user, ajax-toolkit

One of my standard layout button executes JavaScript as: (Only relevant lines posted)

```
var query = "Select id,Name from User where name ='Integration User' Limit 1"; 
var records = sforce.connection.query(query); 
var records1 = records.getArray('records');  
acc.OwnerId= records1[0].Id;
```

This code fails for a user belonging to some custom profile. It gives error saying "can not specify id of undefined".

But it works fine for System administrator. Clearly problem is about querying User object and access on user records.

What permission should i consider for custom profile user to give him ability to execute this SOQL.

I would not like to hard code Integration user id in JavaScript code.

Comment: What's the org wide defaults sharing settings for Users?

Comment: It's set to Private.

Comment: This might be a good use case for `without sharing` code if you can live with using `Apex` instead.

Comment: Thank you Adrian. But is it feasible to use same in ajax toolkit based Javascript code. Or calling a apex method from button would be only option.

Comment: Yes, the Ajax toolkit can allow you to access custom webservices defined in an Apex class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options:

1. Give that profile a permission to View All Users (that's a system permission, not given on the object)
2. Change the Sharing Settings of User to Public Read-only.
3. [Call an webservice apex method from a button](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_and_ajax.htm), just make sure class is *without sharing*
4. Save the Integration User id on a Hierarchy Custom Setting. That way you can reference it in the button and it easy to change on the future.